# Why do exhaustiveness checks work differently for union types?

Tags: typescript, variant, discriminated-union

I'm using exhaustiveness checking as described in [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html)

Exhaustiveness checks seem to work differently for union types as compared to types that are not union types. Why??

For example, in the code below, note that `exhaustivenessCheck1` only works (doesn't type error when it shouldn't) if we assert that `x.kind` is `never`.

However, `exhaustivenessCheck2` only does the right thing if we assert that `x` is `never`.

```
type Variant1 = {
    kind: 1 | 2
}

type Variant2 = {
    kind: 1
} | {
    kind: 2
}

const x: Variant1 = { kind: 1 };


function exhaustivenessCheck1(x: Variant1) {
    switch (x.kind) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            const _x: never = x.kind; // OK
            const _y: never = x; // Error
    }
}

function exhaustivenessCheck2(x: Variant2) {
    switch (x.kind) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            const _x: never = x.kind; // Error
            const _y: never = x; // OK
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link (be sure to enable "strict null checks")](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Atype%20Variant1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%201%20%7C%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Variant2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20Variant1%20%3D%20%7B%20kind%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20exhaustivenessCheck1(x%3A%20Variant1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(x.kind)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%202%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20_x%3A%20never%20%3D%20x.kind%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20_y%3A%20never%20%3D%20x%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20exhaustivenessCheck2(x%3A%20Variant2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(x.kind)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%202%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20_x%3A%20never%20%3D%20x.kind%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20_y%3A%20never%20%3D%20x%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript narrows unions when you use a type-guard. The confusion arises from where the union is.

In `Variant1` the union is on the `kind` member so typescript narrows that union down to `never` on the `default` branch. This means `x` is still of type `Variant1`, and `kind` is still accessible on `x`, just that the type of `kind` at this point is `never`

In `Variant2` the union is on the `x` parameter itself, so `x` is what gets narrowed. This version is also called a discriminated union with `kind` being the discriminator. Since all `kinds` have been checked, on `default` `x` will have been narrowed to `never` and thus accessing `kind` becomes an error.